# auto scale azure spring app URI with terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I need enable auto scale for an spring app hosted by spring app services.I am used below terraform code.

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting" "spring_apps_app_carrier_events" {
  name                = "default_auto_scale"
  enabled             = true
  resource_group_name = module.rg.resource_group_name
  location            = module.rg.resource_group_location
  target_resource_id  = module.spring_apps_app_carrier_events.app_identities[0].principal_id

  profile {
    name = "defaultProfile"

    capacity {
      default = 1
      minimum = 1
      maximum = 2
    }
```

It return errors:

```
Error: Can not parse "target_resource_id" as a resource id: Cannot parse Azure ID: parse "290dc6bd-1895-4e52-bac2-a34e63a138a9": invalid URI for request
```

It seems it need a uri. May u know how can I get the uri of a spring app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When i switch to .value. Error says it has 4 attributes with value. But i do not know what is the 4 attributes. target_resource_id  = module.spring_apps_app_carrier_events.app_identities[0].value

module.spring_apps_app_carrier_events.app_identities[0] is object with 4 attributes
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "value".

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in  my environment.***

Received the same error:

```
│ Error: Can not parse "target_resource_id" as a resource id: Cannot parse Azure ID: parse "xxxxx": invalid URI for request
│   with azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting.spring_apps_app_carrier_events,
```

[image]

***The target_resource_id should not be in just number id form,***

It has to be something like `/subscriptions/xxxxxc/resourceGroups/<myrg>/providers/Microsoft.xxx/xx/sxx`

In your case,

```
target_resource_id  = module.spring_apps_app_carrier_events.app_identities[0].principal_id
```

gives the principal Id which is in “23434354544466”  format which is not correct.

I tried below code with targetid being, resourceId : `/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/ <myrg>/providers/Microsoft.AppPlatform/spring/springcloudappkavya/apps/kaexamplspringcloudapp/deployments/kavyadeploy1`

[image]

**Code:**

```
resource "azurerm_spring_cloud_service" "example" {
  name                = "springcloudappkavya"
  location            =data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku_name            = "S0"

  config_server_git_setting {
    uri          = "https://github.com/Azure-Samples/piggymetrics"
    label        = "config"
    search_paths = ["dir1", "dir2"]
  }

  trace {
    connection_string = azurerm_application_insights.example.connection_string
    sample_rate       = 10.0
  }

  tags = {
    Env = "staging"
  }
}



resource "azurerm_spring_cloud_app" "example" {
  name                = "kaexamplspringcloudapp"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  service_name        = azurerm_spring_cloud_service.example.name

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_spring_cloud_java_deployment" "test" {
  name                = "kavyadeploy1"
  spring_cloud_app_id = azurerm_spring_cloud_app.example.id
  instance_count      = 2
  jvm_options         = "-XX:+PrintGC"

  quota {
    cpu    = "2"
    memory = "4Gi"
  }

  runtime_version = "Java_11"

  environment_variables = {
    "Foo" : "Bar"
    "Env" : "Staging"
  }
}



resource "azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting" "spring_apps_app_carrier_events" {
  name                = "default_auto_scale"
  enabled             = true
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  target_resource_id  = azurerm_spring_cloud_java_deployment.test.id

 // target_resource_id  = .spring_apps_app_carrier_events.app_identities[0].principal_id
 // target_resource_id  =  "18xxxxxe2"


profile {
    name = "metricRules"
    capacity {
      default = 1
      minimum = 1
      maximum = 2
    }
    rule {
      metric_trigger {
        dimensions {
          name     = "AppName"
          operator = "Equals"
          values   = [azurerm_spring_cloud_app.example.name]
        }

        dimensions {
          name     = "Deployment"
          operator = "Equals"
          values   = [azurerm_spring_cloud_java_deployment.test.name]
        }

        metric_name        = "AppCpuUsage"
        metric_namespace   = "microsoft.appplatform/spring"
        metric_resource_id = azurerm_spring_cloud_service.example.id
        time_grain         = "PT1M"
        statistic          = "Average"
        time_window        = "PT5M"
        time_aggregation   = "Average"
        operator           = "GreaterThan"
        threshold          = 75
      }
      scale_action {
        direction = "Increase"
        type      = "ChangeCount"
        value     = 1
        cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Could execute without errors.

[image]

Portal view of Autoscale settings for spring apps.

[image]

**Reference :** [An Azure Spring Cloud Update: Managed Virtual Network and Autoscale are now generally available in Azure Spring Cloud](https://spring.io/blog/2021/03/18/an-azure-spring-cloud-update-managed-virtual-network-and-autoscale-are-now-generally-available-in-azure-spring-cloud)

Comment: Hi . Many thanks for your hint. I tried but i got error return  ```StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> <nil>```

Comment: Check your metric name if it is correct. That error occurs if one uses unsupported metric

Comment: i am using the same "AppCpuUsage" as yours

Comment: @Sanchelz, can you provide your code to investigate where its going wrong